# For what value of k does this system have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I reduced this to reduced row echelon and got the last row as (0, 0 , K-51  |1)
I set k-51=0 and got k=51, which is not the right answer. I did this because it requires me to find a value of K for which the system has no solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide steps. So that we can identify your mistake if any.

Comment: So my line of thought is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solving I get (0, 0 , K+51  |1). Maybe you have mistake in sign.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and easy approach would be to use the determinant and set it equal to $0$.
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & -5 \\ 7 & 16 & k \end{vmatrix}=0$$
You can solve this with a Laplace expansion and obtain:
$$k+51=0$$
Giving you:
$$\boxed{k=-51}$$